# Vue router доступ к статическому документу обходя заглушку

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

У меня есть статический `html` файл с условный названием "Правила", который содержит только текст.
Как сделать так, что бы он открывался по адресу: `mysite.com/docs/rules.html` .
Папка с документом лежит в корне проекта. При переходе по адресу выше, без использования `vue-router` сразу открывается этот документ. Если использовать `vue-router`, то открывается страница заглушка: "Ничего не найдено".

Файл `rules.html` имеет следующий вид:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>
            Rules
        </title>
             .................
```

Пробывал открыть через:

```
        {
            path: '/docs',
            name: 'docs',
            component: () => import('./docs/rules.html')
        },
```

Начинает ругаться на тег `html`

Собственно `router` выглядят так:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('./views/Main.vue')
        },
         ..........
}]
})
```

***UPD***

Предложенный ниже вариант работает, стоит уточнить, можно ли сделать так что бы этот файл открывался в чистом окне без хедера и футера ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте такой компонент: `Rule.vue`

```
<template src="./rules.html">
<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

И подключите его к роутеру, как любой другой компонент. Должно сработать

Comment: Потом импортировать как обычно `component: () => import('./docs/Rule.vue')
`, верно? В таком случае, к сожаление не собирается проект.

Comment: почему не собирается?

Comment: Натолкнулся на этот файл `faq.html` и застрял. Если закомментировать подключение компонента в `routes[]` тогда прекрасно собирает.

Comment: наверное, еще, необходимо переделать html-файл, в валидный, с точки зрения vue, template

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Буду пробовать.

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Может есть возможность открыть файл отдельно? 
В смысле, если импортировать в `template` с тегом `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>` и прочим. на чистую станицу.
 или же стоит загрузить файлы на отдельный сервер и туда к ним обращаться?

Comment: можно и отдельный сервер, но эти страницы уже будут не внутри SPA.  Если же Вам нужно внутри SPA, и управлять данными внутри тега head, то нужно  подключать SSR. Иначе, манипуляции с тегом head  не будут иметь никакого значения